# How to define a global variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to define a variable globally in powershell and get the value in one function and pass that value in different function but I am unable to do so. I googled and tried $global:myvariable but its not working. what wrong am i doing?

here is my code:

```
$global:namerel = $null
Function GET-value{
$uriAccount = $orz + "_apis/release/releases/1914?api-version=6.0"
$responseRels = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 
$namerel = $responseRels.Name
write-host $namerel # it prints the required value
}

Function GET-rel{
$test = GET-value
write-host $namerel # nothing gets printed. its blank
}
```

Comment: Use syntax `$global:namerel` **inside** the functions, otherwise `$namerel` will be just a new variable, local to that function.

Comment: silly me!! please post this as an answer and i will mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks, I've posted it as answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable scoped `global`, you need to use syntax `$global:namerel` **inside** the functions. Without that, variable `$namerel` will be just a new variable, local to that function.

Also, you may not need to use `global`. Scope `script` usually is broad enough. See [About_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: Important side-effect using the $global-prefix: This is NOT working if you run a PS-script as a scheduled task. In that case you need to dfine the var like this: New-Variable test -Scope global -ea 0